# Symmetric Spaces via Lie Group Mod Maximal Compact Subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I've heard it claimed that, under suitable conditions, a symmetric space $M$ is just a quotient of Lie group $G$ by maximal compact subgroup $K$. On the other hand, I am having a tough time finding a reference for this result. For clarity, I'll add some more context now.

I am comfortable with the fact that a Riemannian manifold $M$ that is symmetric space can always be regarded as the quotient $G/G_p$,
where $G:= Isom(M)$ and $G_p$ is the stabilizer of $p \in M$. So, my first question is

(1) Why under these circumstances should the stabilizer $G_p$ of any point $p$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$? (or what extra hypotheses are needed so that $G_p$ is maximal, compact.)

On the other hand, I have the following complementary question

(2) Given a Lie group $G$ and a maximal compact subgroup $K$, why does the quotient $G/K$ admit a Riemannian metric turning it into a symmetric space?

It's likely that I'm missing hypotheses here and there, but I'd like to know under what extra conditions we can answer these two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only approximately true.

First, if you have a semisimple group $G$ and maximal compact subgroup $K$, then for every $G$-invariant metric $g$ on $G/K$, the Riemannian manifold $(G/K,d)$ is a symmetric space of non-compact type (= of sectional curvature $\le 0$ without Euclidean factor). The metric $g$ is not unique, but unique **up to rescaling on each irreducible factor**.

Symmetric spaces that are not of non-compact type cannot be written this way.

Nevertheless every symmetric space $X$ is homogeneous, and hence there exists a connected Lie group $G$ (namely $G=\mathrm{Isom}(X)^\circ$), a compact subgroup $K$, a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric $g$ on $G/K$ such that $(G/K,g)$ is isometric to $X$. Then (i) $K$ is maximal compact in $G$ if and only if one has one of the following equivalent conditions: (ii) $X$ is diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space (iii) $X$ is isometric to a product of a Euclidean space and a symmetric space of non-compact type (iv) $X$ has sectional curvature $\le 0$. This answers (1).

In (2) I guess you mean "when" and not "why":

> *Given a Lie group  and a maximal compact subgroup , when does the quotient $G/K$ admit a Riemannian metric turning it into a symmetric space?*

I don't have a clear-cut answer. If $G$ is semisimple, *every* $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $G/K$ is symmetric. But this also holds for $G$ a simply connected 2-dimensional Lie group ($\mathbf{R}^2$ or $\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{R}$). For a few very special higher-dimensional simply connected solvable Lie groups $G$ (namely minimal Borel subgroups of semisimple Lie groups with no compact factor) there exists some $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $G=G/K$ that is symmetric, but I expect that it's not true for every $G$-invariant Riemannian metric in general (test-case: $\mathbf{R}^2\rtimes\mathbf{R}$ with action by homotheties, Borel in the real Lie group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$). Also the universal covering of $\mathrm{Isom}^+(\mathbf{R}^2)$ has one left-invariant Riemannian metric that is isometric to the Euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^3$, but probably not all left-invariant Riemannian metric are symmetric.

Also most 3-dimensional simply connected solvable Lie groups, say $G_t=\mathbf{R}^2\rtimes\mathbf{R}$ for action $t\mapsto\mathrm{diag}(e^t,e^{ct})$ for $c\notin\{0,1\}$, have no left-invariant Riemannian metric at all that is symmetric. The exceptions are $c=1$ for which some left-invariant Riemannian metric is isometric to the 3-dimensional real hyperbolic space $\mathbf{H}^3$, and $c=0$ for which some left-invariant Riemannian metric is isometric to $\mathbf{H}^2\times\mathbf{R}$.