# Is the space $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/\mathrm{SU}(2)$ a symmetric space?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

My question is: is the homogeneous space $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/\mathrm{SU}(2)$ a symmetric space?

Definitions:  Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup. The pair $(G,H)$ is called a *symmetric space* if there exists an involutive analytic automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $(H_\sigma)_0\subset H\subset H_\sigma$, where $H_{\sigma}$ is the set of fixed points of $\sigma$ and $( H_\sigma)_0$ is the identity component of $H_{\sigma}.$

Using the notation from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group
, $\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})$ is a connected Lie group with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and maximal compact subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(2)$. Let $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}$ be the universal cover. I observed that the inverse image of $\mathrm{U}(2)$ in $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}$ is non-compact, and now the maximal compact subgroup  in $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}$ becomes $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Known information: $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{U}(n)$ is known to be symmetric, see Cartan's list in *Differential
Geometry
and
Symmetric
Spaces*
by Sigurdur Helgason for example. (Different notation! )

I infer that the space might be symmetric, based on the following information:

1. "The examples of class A are completely described by the classification of noncompact simply connected real simple Lie groups. For non-compact type, $G$ is such a group and $K$ is its maximal compact subgroup." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space As $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}$ is simply connected, it follows that $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/SU(2)$ is a symmetric space of non-compact type and of class A there.
2. The answer by YCor [Symmetric Spaces via Lie Group Mod Maximal Compact Subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522403/symmetric-spaces-via-lie-group-mod-maximal-compact-subgroup)
   "Given a Lie group $G$ and a maximal compact subgroup $K$, when does the quotient $G/K$
   admit a Riemannian metric turning it into a symmetric space?
   I don't have a clear-cut answer. If $G$
   is semisimple, every $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $G/K$
   is symmetric. "
   Observe that the Lie algebra of $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}$ is a real simple Lie algebra and hence semisimple. The same result follows.

However I cannot find this space throughout the book *Differential
Geometry
and
Symmetric
Spaces*
by Sigurdur Helgason on the detailed classification of symmetric spaces. The other space $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{U}(n)$ always appears whenever $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/\mathrm{SU}(2)$ should appear.

(Thanks in advance. )

Edit: To clarify the definitions, for the definition of a symmetric space, see the definition of a "symmetric pair" on page 174, Chap IV of the book *Differential
Geometry
and
Symmetric
Spaces*
by Sigurdur Helgason.  For the definition of a Riemannian symmetric space, see the definition of a "Riemannian globally symmetric space" on page 170 of the book. Both are mentioned in Wikipedia, and I am using the same term as Wikipedia. The Proposition 3.4 on page 174 explains their relations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What metric do you put on the universal cover of the symplectic group? If you are not careful, your quotient is only semi-Riemannian.

Comment: Actually assuming the space G/K is symmetric, as in my case K is compact, a compatible Riemannian metric (probably?) always exists as we can average a general metric using Haar measure on K. I haven't check the details. That's why I put bracket "(Riemannian)" :)

Comment: Until you specify which metric one is supposed to use, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan There is a general definition of a symmetric space that is not related to a Riemannian metric, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space

Comment: @MoisheKohan "From the point of view of Lie theory, a symmetric space is the quotient $G/H$ of a connected Lie group $G$ by a Lie subgroup $H$ which is (a connected component of) the invariant group of an involution of $G$. This definition includes more than the Riemannian definition, and reduces to it when $H$ is compact."

Comment: @MoisheKohan do we not get a unique one up to scale induced by the Killing form restricted to the $\mathrm{ad}\mathfrak{k}$ invariant complement which can be identified with the tangent space

Comment: @Callum: Yes, this would be an option that yields a Lorentzian metric. But it is up to OP to decide what is their definition.

Comment: @QingLan: The passage you are quoting is sloppy and partially erroneous. It is not a substitute for an actual revision of your question which currently lack clarity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan For the detailed definition of a symmetric space (as above), see the definition of a "symmetric pair" on page 174, Chap IV of the book I cited. I guess the definition in your mind is the so-called "Riemannian globally symmetric space" defined on page 170 of the book. Both are mentioned in Wikipedia, and I am using the same term as Wikipedia. The Proposition 3.4 on page 174 explains their relations, which is sketched in my comment above. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question using the language of symmetric pairs. I see two naturally occurring pairs in the context of your question. Which one do you mean? Your edit so far did not address the issue

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok I will edit again.

Comment: By the way, YCor in his answer has an implicit assumption that a semisimple group has finite center (or is algebraic). Ditto the quoted Wikipedia passage.

Comment: That's possible. I'll check this out after my final exams...

Answer (score -1):

As you note both point 1 and 2 explicitly say that $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/SU(2)$, as the quotient of a real semisimple Lie group by a maximal compact subgroup, must be Riemannian symmetric. As to why it doesn't appear in Helgason, it is simply that the classification in Helgason is only up to covers (I assume we are looking at table V on page 518). What you have there is simply a cover of $\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{U}(2)$ in the list.

Comment: Sp(4,R)/U(2) is simply connected, hence, admits no nontrivial covers.

Comment: Also, the two homogeneous spaces have different dimensions: $\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{U}(2)$ is $6$-dimensional, while $\widetilde{\mathrm{Sp}(4,\mathbb{R})}/\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is $7$-dimensional.

Comment: @QingLan hmm yeah there is definitely something wrong here then. Are you sure $SU(2)$ is the maximal compact subgroup? It's possible my understanding is faulty but I would have said that the dimension of the maximal compact should be the same for a group and its universal cover.

Comment: @Callum The inverse image of the unitary group is accidentally not compact and it is topologically $\mathbb{R}\times S^3$. The mentioned special unitary group sits inside as a copy of $S^3$.

Comment: @Callum btw you can consider the example $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ :)